# Can decoherence provide a loophole for FTL communication in a system of multiple entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, decoherence

I am a layperson when it comes to the study of quantum mechanics and do not quite have the expertise to properly evaluate the questions I am going to post here.  But here it goes. Suppose three entangled photons are created using the following process -

A.  A blue photon that is polarized both in the vertical and horizontal plane is sent through a special crystal converting it into a pair of lower energy, red photons that are now entangled with each other.

B.  One of the two entangled red photons is sent through another crystal that creates a pair of entangled, lower energy, infrared photons.

C.  The infrared pair of photons are now also entangled with the remaining red photon.

For the sake of argument, let's label the three particles in such a way that the leftover red photon is called "Alice's photon" and the two infrared photons are called "Bob's photon" and "Charlie's photon", respectively.

Now a couple questions arise.  Will interfering with Alice's Photon cause decoherence across the whole system?  And more specifically, will this cause decoherence between Bob and Charlie's photons?  If these two questions are answered in the affirmative, then it follows that a faster-than-light communication method will likely avail itself.  Imagine that multiple sets of Alice, Bob, and Charlies's photons are created in the same manner described above.  Let's say 20 sets of these photon triplets are generated and put into two groups -- Group 1 and Group 2, each with 10 sets of entangled photon triplets.  Now suppose that all of Bob and Charlie's photons are moved far away from Alice's photons, say the distance to the moon, approximately 250,000 miles off.  Now let's suppose for Group 1, all of Alice's photons are interfered with and then precisely at that same moment, all of Bob and Charlie's Group 1 photons are checked for anticorrelation.  This anticorrelation should not be statistically significant and thus prove that entanglement was destroyed.  It should be possible to ascertain whether entanglement was destroyed by action at the terrestrial location BEFORE such information could be communicated via a classical channel at a luminal or subluminal speed.  For the control, entanglement could be tested between Bob and Charlie's Group 2 photons.  A statistically significant anticorrelation should exist between these particles, given that nothing was done to cause decoherence between these pairs.

But the question is, would there be a statistically significant difference in the anticorrelation of Bob and Charlie's Group 1 photons when compared to the same for the Group 2 photons?  Where does the basis for this loophole breakdown, if it is indeed not valid?

Comment: In mainstream physics there are no known “loopholes” for FTL communication using entanglement, regardless of the number of particles.

Comment: WillO's Law for questions about using entanglement for FTL communication:  If the question claims to specify a protocol that requires making measurements on an entangled system, but does not actually specify either the measurements or the entangled state, it's time to stop reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's put your words into a form that's easier to work with by writing out the states at each stage of the process.

Let $|v\rangle$ be the state of a photon that is vertically polarized, and let $|h\rangle$ be the state of a photon which is horizontally polarized. Then your initial photon that is "polarized in both the vertical and horizontal planes" is represented by the state

$$|\psi\rangle=a|v\rangle+b|h\rangle$$

for two (complex) numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$. Now suppose the "special crystal" produces two (lower-energy) entangled copies of the incoming photon with perfectly correlated polarizations: in other words, for the one-photon state $|v\rangle$ it produces the two-photon state $|vv\rangle$, and for the one-photon state $|h\rangle$ it produces the two-photon state $|hh\rangle$. For all further analysis, the actual energy of the photon is immaterial, as we only care about the polarizations from a communications perspective, so we can ignore the differences in energy. So, after putting your initial photon through the special crystal, you would have the state:

$$|\Psi\rangle=a|vv\rangle+b|hh\rangle$$

and after putting the *second* photon through an identical special crystal (we simply ignore the first photon in $|\Psi\rangle$ for this part), we have the state:

$$|\Phi\rangle=a|vvv\rangle+b|hhh\rangle$$

So now we have three photons which are all entangled in such a way that, while none of them have definite spin until measured, they all must be measured to have the *same* spin.

Measurement of only one photon is represented by taking the partial inner product over that photon's states; when we do this, regardless of which one we choose, we have a probability of $|a|^2$ of measuring the photon as vertically-polarized, meaning that the remaining photons will be in the state $|vv\rangle$, and a probability of $|b|^2$ of measuring the photon as horizontally-polarized, meaning that the remaining photons will be in the state $|hh\rangle$.

Now, we can answer the main questions:

> Will interfering with Charlie's Photon cause decoherence across the whole system? And more specifically, will this cause decoherence between Bob and Charlie's photons?

Interfering with Charlie's photon means acting on the third photon in $|\Phi\rangle$ with some function that turns $|v\rangle$ into $c_{vv}|v\rangle+c_{vh}|h\rangle$ and $|h\rangle$ into $c_{hv}|v\rangle+c_{hh}|h\rangle$, where, as before, $|c_{vv}|^2+|c_{vh}|^2=1$ and $|c_{hv}|^2+|c_{hh}|^2=1$. Doing that will leave us with the state:

$$|\Omega\rangle=ac_{vv}|vvv\rangle+ac_{vh}|vvh\rangle+bc_{hv}|hhv\rangle+bc_{hh}|hhh\rangle$$

Now, as you can see, Charlie's photon is different from the other two. Let's examine what happens when each of them measures their photon:

---

**What Alice and Bob measure**

By taking the partial inner product over one of the first two photons, we can see that the probability of measuring a vertical polarization is

$$|ac_{vv}|^2+|ac_{vh}|^2=|a|^2(|c_{vv}|^2+|c_{vh}|^2)=|a|^2\cdot 1=|a|^2$$

which would leave the system in the state $c_{vv}|vv\rangle+c_{vh}|vh\rangle$. Assuming this measurement result, the other untampered photon in the system has a 100 percent chance of being measured as vertically polarized, which leaves the system in the state $c_{vv}|v\rangle+c_{vh}|h\rangle$. Likewise, the probability of measuring a horizontal polarization is

$$|bc_{hv}|^2+|bc_{hh}|^2=|b|^2(|c_{hv}|^2+|c_{hh}|^2)=|b|^2\cdot 1=|b|^2$$

which would leave the system in the state $c_{hv}|hv\rangle+c_{hh}|hh\rangle$. As before, assuming this measurement result, the other untampered photon has a 100 percent chance of being measured as horizontally polarized, which leaves the system in the state $c_{hv}|v\rangle+c_{hh}|h\rangle$.

As you can see, **neither Alice nor Bob measure anything different than before!** Their measurement probabilities for their photons remain exactly the same as before Charlie's photon is tampered with. As such, there is **no way to tell**, from looking at their photon alone, that Charlie's photon has been tampered with at all! This means that Charlie can't influence their measurements by tampering with his photon. (To be clear, the order of measurements doesn't actually matter here; you'll get the same results if Charlie measures first, as we'll see in the next section).

---

**What Charlie measures**

Once again taking the partial inner product over the third photon, the probability that Charlie measures a vertically-polarized photon is

$$|ac_{vv}|^2+|bc_{hv}|^2$$

which leaves the system in the state $\frac{ac_{vv}}{\sqrt{|ac_{vv}|^2+|bc_{hv}|^2}}|vv\rangle+\frac{bc_{hv}}{\sqrt{|ac_{vv}|^2+|bc_{hv}|^2}}|hh\rangle$. Given this measurement result, Alice and Bob have a probability of $\frac{|ac_{vv}|^2}{|ac_{vv}|^2+|bc_{hv}|^2}$ of both measuring vertically-polarized photons, and they have a probability of $\frac{|bc_{hv}|^2}{|ac_{vv}|^2+|bc_{hv}|^2}$ of both measuring horizontally-polarized photons.

$$$$

Likewise, the probability that Charlie measures a horizontally-polarized photon is

$$|ac_{vh}|^2+|bc_{hh}|^2$$

which leaves the system in the state $\frac{ac_{vh}}{\sqrt{|ac_{vh}|^2+|bc_{hh}|^2}}|vv\rangle+\frac{bc_{hh}}{\sqrt{|ac_{vh}|^2+|bc_{hh}|^2}}|hh\rangle$. Given this measurement result, Alice and Bob have a probability of $\frac{|ac_{vh}|^2}{|ac_{vh}|^2+|bc_{hh}|^2}$ of both measuring vertically-polarized photons, and they have a probability of $\frac{|bc_{hh}|^2}{|ac_{vh}|^2+|bc_{hh}|^2}$ of both measuring horizontally-polarized photons.

$$$$

There are two main conclusions you can draw from this:

- **Charlie knows when his *own* photon is being tampered with**, since the probabilities of measurement of vertical or horizontal polarization of his photon are different than before tampering.
- **No matter what, Alice and Bob's photons are still perfectly correlated**. There is zero probability, no matter what, of the system being left in a state containing $|vh\rangle$ or $|hv\rangle$ after Charlie's measurement. And, if you add up the probabilities over Charlie's possible measurements, the *total* probability that Alice and Bob measure a particular polarization direction is still the same as before measurement, and before interference.

---

So, in general, by carrying out the calculations above, we confirm that Alice and Bob **cannot tell** that Charlie's photon has been changed if they only inspect their own photons. In order to detect any sign of tampering, at least one of them **must** communicate with Charlie classically (which, remember, is limited to lightspeed) to ask him what his measurement result was. Therefore, **no FTL communication is possible** here, since this scheme requires ordinary classical communication to actually yield any information at all.

As an aside, your scheme sounds somewhat similar to an algorithm for *quantum key distribution* called E91 (developed by Artur Ekert in 1991, hence the name; for details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution). It's a way to distribute a shared secret key, using multiple sets of entangled photons, that will break if anyone tries to eavesdrop on the transmission. E91 relies on classical communication between the two participants in order to compare their measurement results and detect eavesdropping.

Comment: Thank you for this exaustive and enlightening answer.  I really appreciate it.  I suppose done I'm trying to propose anything that could potentially violate causality --for awhile at least!

Answer (score 0):

Forget measurement "causing" decoherence at a remote location. Decoherence is a physical process and propagates at almost the speed of light. What you are thinking of is collapse of the wave function. In some interpretations, measurement causes collapse. These interpretations have to formulate the collapse hypothesis with the right rules. It's not too difficult. Alice's measurement is on her own state and the resultant collapse separates her state from the still-entangled state of Bob and Charlie. So they are not affected at all. That's not always spelled out when talking about collapse theories, but it should be!

Ironically, decoherence obviates the need for collapse - at least it does if you carry it all the way through to the Many Worlds picture :)

So no, there's no loophole unless you introduce a (redundant) hypothesis about collapse and then forget to apply the rules correctly.